# Нажатие двух клавиш сразу

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Итак, решил я, значит, начать изучение языка Java, изучал себе, изучал, по обучающим роликам создал что-то похожее на змейку (игра). И вот все бы ничего, но при нажатии двух кнопок одновременно происходит ужасное - змейка съедает сама себя. Подскажите, где же ошибка?

Вся суть в том, что мне нужно сделать так, чтобы проверялось нажатие двух кнопок одновременно, и если они нажаты, змейка не поворачивала. Ну, надеюсь, поймете.

P.S. Я еще совсем начинающий, не ругайтесь сильно на мой мега код. )
P.P.S. Все лишнее я убрал, поэтому не пишите "втф афтар у тебя же змейка не объявлена".

```
public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public static final int SCALE  = 32;
    public static final int WIDTH  = 20;
    public static final int HEIGHT  = 20;
    public static  int SPEED  = 10;

    Snake s = new Snake(10, 10, 9, 10);
    Timer t = new Timer(1000/SPEED, this);

    private class keyboard extends KeyAdapter{
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent Kevent){
            int key = Kevent.getKeyCode();

            //я пытался...
            if((((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT & s.direction!= 2)& key != KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) & key != KeyEvent.VK_UP )& key != KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) s.direction = 0;
            if((((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN & s.direction!= 3)& key != KeyEvent.VK_UP) & key != KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT )& key != KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)  s.direction = 1;
            if((((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT & s.direction != 0)& key != KeyEvent.VK_UP) & key != KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT )& key != KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) s.direction = 2;
            if((((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP & s.direction != 1)& key != KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) & key != KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT )& key != KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) s.direction = 3;
        }
    }

    public Main(){
       t.start();
       addKeyListener(new keyboard());
       setFocusable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Amazing snake");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setSize(WIDTH * SCALE+6 , HEIGHT * SCALE + 29);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(new Main());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        s.move();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: @nontoup, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посмотрел в сторону стека, чтобы обрабатывать все в порядке очереди (в google: java стек). Можно попробовать флаги выставлять при нажатии клавиши и по таймеру выставлять в false и выполнять, где внутри таймера проверялось бы логичность действия.

Посмотрите stackoverflow, там, конечно, нет прямо ответа на Ваш вопрос, но, может, идею под себя адаптируете:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301775/get-key-combinations?lq=1
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752999/how-do-i-handle-multiple-key-presses-in-java

Comment: Большое спасибо! Попробую разобраться :)

Comment: на меня нашло озарение! Это не из-за нажатия двух кнопок, а из-за слишком быстрого их поочередного нажатия. Звучит довольно-таки странно, согласен

Comment: @nontoup, рад, что разобрались! Ну, собственно, значит я верно мыслил, что надо все ввести в очередь и по винтикам разбирать операцию.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что вы обрабатываете одно нажатие. Один раз нажали - обработали, второй раз нажали - обрабатываем новое нажатие, и так далее. Для того, чтобы обрабатывать несколько и более нажатий, необходимо их всех где-нибудь хранить. Первое, что приходит в голову - создать переменные типа boolean под каждую кнопку. Это решение будет, в принципе, верным, но в то же время костыльным. Допустим, если мы захотим поймать какую-либо новую кнопку (которую ранее не ловили), нам придётся создавать новую переменную. Для того, чтобы решить эту проблему мы создадим список, который будет хранить все нажатые кнопки.

```
public class Keys{

    public static KeyAdapter DEFAULT_KEY_ADAPTER = new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyCode) {
            press(keyCode.getKeyCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyCode) {
            reset(keyCode.getKeyCode());
        }
    };

    // все нажатые кнопки (в данный момент)
    private static final List<Integer> keyChain = new ArrayList<>();;

    // true, если кнопка с кодом keyCode нажата
    public static boolean isPressed(int keyCode) {
        return keyChain.contains(keyCode);
    }

    // вызвать, как только была нажата кнопка с кодом keyCode
    public static void press(int keyCode) {
        if (!isPressed(keyCode)) {
            keyChain.add(keyCode);
        }
    }

    // вызвать, как только была отпущена кнопка с кодом keyCode
    public static void reset(int keyCode) {
        if (isPressed(keyCode)) {
            keyChain.remove(keyChain.indexOf(keyCode));
        }
    }

    public static void clear() {
        keyChain.clear();
    }
}
```

То есть мы создаём класс, независимый от конкретной реализации KeyAdapter (но для удобства в коде я привёл стандартный). Далее в цикле проверяем нажатые кнопки:

```
if (Keys.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
    // TODO: add action
}
if (Keys.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
    // TODO: add action
}
if (Keys.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
    // TODO: add action
}
if (Keys.isPressed(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) {
    // TODO: add action
}
```