# Как сделать движение по диагонали? Спасите

Tags: java, клавиатура

Как при помощи KeyListener заставить какой-либо объект двигаться по диагонали, т.е. при нажатии **двух клавиш**, к примеру, WD (движение вправо-вверх)

---

Вот отрывок, x и y - переменные int. Я не стал всё писать, там просто много лишнего

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
      if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W){
            jlabel.setBounds(x, y-=3, 400, 400);
      }
}
```

Comment: а что у вас не получается?

Comment: --y, ++x (путем изменения координат)

Comment: А можно пример как двигаетесь при помощи одной кнокпи?

Comment: Ну, я пишу, к примеру, в if() два условия через &&, чтобы как бы он считывал сразу с двух кнопок, но это не катит. Мне надо чтобы Jlabel перемещался по-диагонали, при нажатии двух клавиш

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/399597/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83

Comment: Запоминайте нажатые и ещё не отжатые кнопки